# PHP - fpdf, cell переносится на новую страницу

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Вот такой простой код выводит прямоугольник на вторую страницу, хотя должен просто рисовать его на первой. Экспериментально выяснил, что если уменьшить высоту этого прямоугольника до 1/3 вместо 1/2 - оно не переносится.
Такое ощущение, что мешает или footer, или поля, но поля вродь-как убраны, а колонтитулы по умолчанию нулевые.

```
$maketW = 90;
$maketH = 50;
$maketW2 = floor($maketW/2);
$maketH2 = floor($maketH/2);
$maketW4 = floor($maketW/4);
$maketH4 = floor($maketH/4);

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->SetMargins(0,0,0);
$pdf->AddPage('L',[$maketW,$maketH]);



// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
  $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
  $pdf->SetXY($maketW4,$maketH4);
  $pdf->cell($maketW2,$maketH2,'test sign',1,0,'L',0);

// output to browser
$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 1):

Два решения:

1. убрать автоперенос

   ```
   $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
   ```
2. убрать поля 2см по умолчанию, поставив их в ноль.

   ```
   $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,0);
   ```